# .oga файл python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Хотел написать Telegram бота, который расшифровывает голосовое сообщение и переводит его в текстовый формат, но столкнулся с проблемой: для всех известных мне библиотек распознавания речи нужен формат .wav или .mp3 на вход, но конвертировать .oga файл не удаётся никакой библиотекой или методом. Повторюсь, не .ogg, а именно .oga. Код прилагать смысла не вижу, меня интересует именно конвертация форматов. Спасибо заранее за ответы!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Всякий файл .oga можно "превратить" в привычный .ogg путем простого изменения расширения, при этом никакого преобразования формата не требуется.

Comment: Добрый день, спасибо за ваш ответ! Дело в том, что в таком случае я могу самостоятельно прослушать файл, то есть, со сменой формата не случается ошибки. Но библиотека SpeechRecognition не может 'прослушать' данный файл, ей нужен формат .wav. А тут уже не справится в конвертировании формата 'руками', SpeechRecognition выдаёт в таком случае ошибку.

Comment: получилось конвертировать? Можешь код опубликовать?